# About generator of a cyclic commutator subgroup

Tags: group-theory

The following problem appears in the book of I. Macdonald on Group Theory:

> Let G be a group such that
>
> (1) $[G,G]$ is infinite cyclic.
>
> (2) $[G,G]\subseteq Z(G)$.
>
> Prove that $[G,G]$ is generated by a single *commutator*.

I want to consider this question with a different face.

**Q.** Is there a group $G$ satisfying only (1), but $[G,G]$ is *not* generated by a commutator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is no, there is no such example.

If (1) and holds, but (2) does not then, since the automorphism group of an infinite cyclic group has order $2$,  the centralizer $H$ of $[G,G] = \langle z \rangle$ in $G$ has index $2$ in $G$, and $t^{-1}zt=z^{-1}$ for $t \in G \setminus H$. Choose such a $t$.

Suppose first that $H$ is abelian. Then $[G,G]$ is generated by the elements $[t,h]$ for $h \in H$. Since $H$ is abelian, we have  $[t,hk] = [t,h][t,k]$ for $h,k \in H$, and so the map $H \to [G,G]$ defined by $h \mapsto [t,h]$ is a surjective homomorphism, and hence there must exist $h \in H$ with $[t,h] = z$.

Otherwise $H$ is nonabelian, and there exist $h,k \in H$ with $[h,k] = z^n$ for some $n>0$. Then $t^{-1}ht = hz^i$ and $t^{-1}kt = kz^j$ for some $i,j$, and so $z^{-n} = t^{-1}z^nt = t^{-1}[h,k]t = [hz^i,kz^j] = [h,k] = z^n$, a contradiction.

Comment: Very nice answer.